# Apache2 www1 instead of www

Tags: server, apache2

So I created a very simple site containing only index.html with the text 'welcome'.
the virtual host of this site is as follows:

```
ServerAdmin email@email.com
ServerName name.com
ServerAlias www.name.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/name.com/public_html
```

This works just fine. Then I make another site which I want to be `www1.name.com` with the text `www1`.

I do practicly the same, I make a folder `/var/www1/name.com/public_html` with `index.html` in it
I copy the previous file and change  it

```
ServerAlias www1.name.com
DocumentRoot /var/www1/name.com/public_html
```

but when going to www1.name.com, I get the text 'Welcome' and not 'www1'.
Can anyone please help me with this?

And yes I always do `a2ensite/a2dissite` and `service apache2 restart`

Comment: Why did you need to create `www1`? I believe the default location is `/var/www`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `VirtualHost` tags are fine.
It's probably because the `ServerAlias` isn't used if there is no `ServerName` present.
Try it again after changing `ServerAlias` to `ServerName` in your second `VirtualHost`.

A good reminder is to set `ServerName` for the first name and use `ServerAlias` for any additional aliases.

Do note though if you are going to use another directory (outside of /var/www) that the permissions are set properly. Also if `SELinux` is used, the appropriate context needs to be set for that directory. But that's properly not an issue unless you enable `SELinux` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Clarification of few basic points:

- Within Ubuntu, `/var/www` is the default directory where the user's web content must be stored. This is defined into the global Apache's configuration file: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, by the directives:

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ```
- There is no direct link between the VirtualHost's name and its `DocumentRoot` directory name.
- The directive `ServerName` defines the general server's name or the name of certain VirtualHost when it is placed into its definition - between the `<VirtualHost>` tags.
- With a view of the effective VHs management, usually, the definition of each individual VirtualHost is placed in a separate configuration file.
- The directive `ServerName` is required for each VirtualHost.
- The directive `ServerAlias` is not required. We can think about it as place, where we can type one or more synonyms of `ServerName`.

According to these points, my suggestion is next:

- Create two separate directories located in `/var/www`, as the example from the question they could be:

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /var/www/www.name.com/public_html
  sudo mkdir -p /var/www/www1.name.com/public_html
  ```
- Create configuration file for the first VirtualHost:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.name.com.conf
  ```

  Its content should be something as:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.name.com
      ServerAlias name.com 
      ServerAdmin email@email.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/www.name.com/public_html
      <Directory /var/www/www.name.com/public_html>
          Options None FollowSymLinks
          # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
          AllowOverride All
          DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Create configuration file for the second VirtualHost:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/www1.name.com.conf
  ```

  Its content should be something as:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www1.name.com
      ServerAdmin email@email.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/www1.name.com/public_html
      <Directory /var/www/www1.name.com/public_html>
          Options None FollowSymLinks
          # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
          AllowOverride All
          DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Require all granted            
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Disable all existing VirtualHost's configurations, if it is needed: `sudo a2dissite "*.conf"`.
- Enable the new configuration files:

  ```
  sudo a2ensite www.name.com.conf www1.name.com.conf
  ```
- Restart Apache:

  - Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo service apache2 restart`
  - Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`
- Put some index.html pages into `public_html/` folders and try to access the two domains (`http://www...` and `http://www1...`) through the browser.